# How to get informations about electrons webview crashed event

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on a project which is currently using electron 7.2.1
In this project i am using a webview, for this webview i am listening for several events.

- did-fail-load
- did-start-loading
- did-finish-load

and as well

- crashed (see: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#event-crashed)

Example:

```
webview.addEventListener('crashed', function () {
        console.error('webview just crashed') 
})
```

In some rare cases it happens that my webview is crashing. The related event is thrown, but i am wondering if or how i can get informations about the actual crash event and it's reason.
Is there an error object / error code or similar i can use for logging & debugging?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the type definition of `webConents` from `electron.d.ts` As you can see the crashed event listener will be receiving the 2 parameters. `event` and `killed`

```
/**
 * Emitted when the renderer process crashes or is killed.
 */
on(event: 'crashed', listener: (event: Event,
                                killed: boolean) => void): this;
```

So you can use like this to check the details.

```
webview.webContents.on('crashed', (event, killed) => {
    console.log(event, killed)
});
```

Comment: nice hint that you can look it up there.

Comment: unfortunately he i right about it when it comes to "unresponsive" and similar. but not part of this question.